# Unflatten a JSON Object into nested JSON Object using Dataweave 2.0

Tags: json, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have this Flattened Object

```
{
  "abc.def.ghi": "foo",
  "abc.def.jkl": "bar"
}
```

I want to write a dataweave to convert it into the original object, i.e.

```
{
  "abc": {
    "def": {
      "ghi": "foo",
      "jkl": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to avoid hard coding the keys because it is a quite large object, So I do not want something like this:

```
%dw 2.0
var test = {
    "abc.def.ghi": "foo",
    "abc.def.jkl": "bar"
}
output application/json
---
{
    abc: {
        def: {
            ghi: test."abc.def.ghi",
            jkl: test."abc.def.jkl"
        }
    }
}
```

Can I use some combination of available dataweave functions for achieving this?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
%dw 2.0
var test = {
    "abc.def.ghi": "foo",
    "abc.def.jkl": "bar"
}
output application/json
---
test mapObject ((value, key) -> 
    (key as String splitBy  ".")[-1 to 0]  
         reduce ((item, acc = value) -> 
             (item): acc     
/*
   First item=ghi,acc=foo => acc = {ghi: "foo"} 
   next item=def, acc={ghi: "foo"} => acc={def:{ghi:"foo"}}
*/
    )
)
```

But this would generate some kind of separate pair of the nested JSON. Here is the output of the above code:

```
{
  "abc": {
    "def": {
      "ghi": "foo"
    }
  },
  "abc": {
    "def": {
      "jkl": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to @olamiral solution, but simplified and supports arrays.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

// Creates a array of key-value tuples with the object structure. 
// I was not able to use entriesOf() because I had to modify the key to split it
var tuples = payload pluck ((value, key, index) -> 
    { 
        k: key splitBy("."), 
        v: value}
    )

// Using groupBy, group the childs and maps to an object structure.
fun flatToObject(tuples, index) =
    (tuples groupBy $.k[index]) mapObject ((groupedTuples, key, idx) -> 
        if(groupedTuples[0].k[index + 1]?) 
            // Has more levels
            { (key): flatToObject(groupedTuples,index + 1) }
        else 
            // It's a leaf
            { (key): if (sizeOf(groupedTuples.v) > 1)
                    // It has an array of values
                    groupedTuples.v 
                else 
                    // It has a single value
                    groupedTuples.v[0]
            }
    )
---
flatToObject(tuples,0)
```

With this payload:

```
{
    "abc.def.ghi": "foo",
    "abc.def.jkl": "bar",
    "abc.de.f": "bar2",
    "abc.def.jkm": "bar3",
    "abc.de.f": 45
}
```

It's producing this output:

```
{
  "abc": {
    "def": {
      "ghi": "foo",
      "jkl": "bar",
      "jkm": "bar3"
    },
    "de": { 
      "f": ["bar2", 45]
    }
  }
}
```

This solution does not support mixing simple values and objects in the same array.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this is to use the **update** operator that was introduce in 4.3. With this operator we can do upsert (insert the value when is not present or update if present) Using that and a reduce we can go from each of the part of the expression and do the proper update

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::util::Values


fun upsert(object: {}, path:Array<String>, value: Any): Object = do {
    path match {
        case [] -> object
        case [x ~ xs] -> 
                if(isEmpty(xs))
                    object update  {
                        case ."$(x)"! -> value                                
                    }
                else
                    object update  {
                        case selected at ."$(x)"! -> 
                            //selected is going to be null when the value is not present  
                            upsert(selected default {}, xs, value)
                    }  
    }
}
---
payload 
    pluck ((value, key, index) -> {key: key, value: value})
    reduce ((item, resultObject = {} ) -> do {
        upsert(resultObject, (item.key as String splitBy '.') , item.value)
    })
```

Comment: I really wanted to use the nee upsert with update for this. But I was struggling with using dynamic value in the "case v at .(DYNAMICPATH)". Whete did you find this notation? I could not find it anywhere.

Comment: I will review the docs to see if it is not present. I know this because I wrote it ;) it is not a path it is just one field that is why I need to do it recursively.

Comment: Nice! Can you also please explain how **case [x ~ xs]** is splitting the array into two parts?

Comment: This is a head and tail deconstruct. You can use it in any pattern match. Is a simple way to iterate over a collection.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following dataweave expression, based on this Apisero article, written by Mohammad Mazhar Ansari: https://apisero.com/property-to-yaml-file-conversion-using-mulesoft/

```
%dw 2.0
var test = {
    "abc.def.ghi": "foo",
    "abc.def.jkl": "bar"
}
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
fun generateArray (obj) = obj pluck (v, k) -> (k): v
fun isSubChildExists (key) = (((key) splitBy ("."))[1] != null)
fun propToJSON(key, value) = if (isSubChildExists(key)) {
   (substringBefore(key, ".")) : propToJSON(substringAfter(key, "."), value)
}
else
   (key): value
fun arrToObj(arr) = arr reduce ((env, obj={}) -> obj ++ env)
fun CombineObjBasedOnKey (Obj) =
if (typeOf(Obj) == Array and sizeOf(Obj..) > 1)
((Obj groupBy (item, index) -> keysOf(item)[0]) mapObject ((value, key, index) ->
   (if (typeOf(value) == Array)
       (key): CombineObjBasedOnKey(value..'$key')
   else if (typeOf(value) == String)
       value
   else
       (key): value
) as Object))
else
   Obj[0]
---
CombineObjBasedOnKey(generateArray(test) map ((item, index) -> item mapObject ((value, key, index) -> propToJSON((key), value))
))
```

Output:

```
{
  "abc": {
    "def": {
      "ghi": "foo",
      "jkl": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```